# Vim showing a python2 error when writing in python3

Tags: python, vim, text-editor

Vim shows an error on line 4 of the picture below, which in python 2 is actually an error but not in python 3 which I have check by running it.

How do I tell vim I am writing in python 3 to avoid it pointing out these errors?

Also I am using the [deep-space](https://github.com/tyrannicaltoucan/vim-deep-space) theme for vim which hasn't been updated for 2 years, are there any that support the latest version of python3?

[image: Vim_python3_error]

Comment: Maybe ask in [vi.se]?

Comment: Isn’t this more of a general tech support question?

Comment: Vim does not have embedded python "linter". That's some plugin you use. Conisult its documentation.

Comment: f-strings were added to Python at version 3.6. It could be that your vim is built with Python 3 but version like 3.4 or 3.5.

Comment: Vim doesn't provide syntax check natively, so I think you are using some other plugin. See the plugin documentation for help.